# Matlab: Convert date imported form excel to readable format?

Tags: matlab, date, plot, graph

I have imported data from excel file.
After importing date date, my date looks like:

```
0.641238425925926
0.641932870370370
0.642627314814815
0.643321759259259
0.644016203703704
```

I used `datestr(Time)`.
I am getting date data in the format I need, however the data is not in tabular format. I need to plot the data. So I need to have all of it in tabular format.

`datevec` works, however, it gives Hour, Minute separately. Not sure how to combine it all.

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect those numbers to be full dates (and by "full dates" I mean temporal points including both a date and a time), then you are probably doing something wrong when reading the Excel spreadsheet. But since you are only speaking about hours and minutes, I think you are on the right path and you only want to consider time.

```
time = [
    0.641238425925926
    0.641932870370370
    0.642627314814815
    0.643321759259259
    0.644016203703704
];

time_str = cellstr(datestr(data,'HH:mm:ss'));
```

The above code will produce a 5-by-1 cell array of character vectors, which is not good for plotting. As you said, `datevec` will split your datetime values, and it's not good either. I suggest you to keep your values into their current numeric format and use them in order to define your `x-axis` points. Once the plot is drawn, you can always convert your tick labels into a more readable format:

```
time = [
    0.641238425925926
    0.641932870370370
    0.642627314814815
    0.643321759259259
    0.644016203703704
];

value = [
    1
    3
    4
    0
    2
];

plot(time,value);
datetick('x','HH:mm:ss');
```

As you can see, this loses the seconds precision because of rounding. So, to keep the highest possible precision:

```
% ...

plot(time,value);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',cellstr(datestr(data,'HH:mm:ss')));
```